# how to work with wave-component under a-frame 1.3.0? It is working only with a-frame 0.8.2

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I have used wave-component with A-frame version 0.8.2. That component is not working with A-frame version 1.3.0. Do you know a solution for this?

Thank you for your help.

```
<html>

    <script>

        AFRAME.registerComponent('wave-component', {
            schema: {
                texturepath: {type: 'asset'}
            },
            init: function () {

                console.log(this.data.texturepath.src)

                var el = this.el;
                const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 3, 100, 60);

                // Creating a material with the texture path provided
                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map: loader.load(this.data.texturepath.src),
                    transparent: true
                });

                var wave = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

                // wave.rotation.set(-0.1, 0, 0);
                wave.rotation.set(-0.3, 0.0, -0.0);
                // wave.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
                const clock = new THREE.Clock();

                el.setObject3D('WaveMesh', wave);

                // Function to animate each vertex of the texture to simulate a wave effect
                function animate() {
                    const t = clock.getElapsedTime();

                    wave.geometry.vertices.map(v => {
                        // const waveX1 = 0.15 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3);
                        const waveX1 = 0.15 * Math.sin(v.x * 2 + t * 3);
                        // const waveX2 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 3 + t * 2);
                        const waveX2 = 0.05 * Math.sin(v.x * 5 + t * 2);
                        // const waveY1 = 0.001 * Math.sin(v.y * 3 + t * 0.5);
                        const waveY1 = 0.1 * Math.sin(v.y * 10 + t * 0.5);
                        // const multi = (v.x + 2.5) / 5;
                        const multi = (v.x + 0.1) / 5;

                        v.z = (waveX1 + waveX2 + waveY1) * multi;
                    })

                    wave.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                }
                animate();
            }
        });


    </script>
```

This script works fine with A-frame 0.8.2 but does not with A-frame 1.3.0

Comment: Why is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: Moritz. The browser shows nothing and the console says: core:a-node:error Failure loading node:   TypeError: wave.geometry.vertices is undefined. Thank you.